# JQuery UI draggable and droppable but not sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 lists on my webpage with the following scenario:

1. List A is sortable.
2. List B is draggable and droppable with List A but NOT sortable within itself.

I have tried examples from JQuery UI and looked up some posts on SO as well. Can't seem to get #2 working.

Anybody have any insight?

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
$( "#listA" ).droppable({accept: "#listB li"}).sortable({
}).disableSelection();


$( "#listB li" ).draggable({
    appendTo: "body",
    helper: "clone",
    connectToSortable: '#listA'
}).droppable({accept: "#listA"});


<ul id="listA">
  <li id="ul_item_1">item-1</li>
  <li id="ul_item_2">item-2</li>
  <li id="ul_item_3">item-3</li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<ul id="listB">
  <li id="ul_item_4">item-4</li>
  <li id="ul_item_5">item-5</li>
  <li id="ul_item_6">item-6</li>
</ul>
```

Here is the JSFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/kmenezes/8eCJH/

I have got ListA to work as expected (draggable, droppable and sortable). I cannot get an item to drop into ListB. That is all I need to get this working.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us some code ? What you have tried, so far ?

Comment: could you add a fiddle ?

Comment: Your code is working here http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/bMSKf/ , Or I don't understand what your after.

Comment: @Trevor: I need ListB to accept an item from ListA. That is not working.

Comment: Okay so you want ListB to accept an item from ListA but not have it be sortable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had trouble getting it to work with how you have it set up in your example..  I made a couple of work a rounds that hopefully will be helpful to you.

Example 1

- You can move between list A and list B but if you try to sort list B then it gets reverted.

HTML

```
<ul class="sortable" id="listA">
  <li id="ul_item_1">item-1</li>
  <li id="ul_item_2">item-2</li>
  <li id="ul_item_3">item-3</li>
</ul>
<br>
<br>
<ul class="sortable" id="listB">
  <li id="ul_item_4">item-4</li>
  <li id="ul_item_5">item-5</li>
  <li id="ul_item_6">item-6</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery

```
$('#listA, #listB').sortable({
  helper: "clone",
  placeholder: "selected-option",
  forcePlaceholderSize: true,
  dropOnEmpty: true,
  revert: true,
  connectWith: '.sortable',
  tolerance: "pointer",
  cursor: "move",
  beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
    if($(ui.helper).parent().attr('id') === 'listB' && $(ui.placeholder).parent().attr('id') === 'listB')
       return false; 
  }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/PK3LE/

UPDATE

mccc provided an update to example 1 that doesn't throw an error. (see comments)

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PK3LE/8/

Example 2

- Similar to Example1 except for List2 gets cloned like you have in your example..

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/PK3LE/2/

Comment: Thanks so much. Both the examples work well. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @Pipe2Path your welcome please mark this answer as accepted if you feel it answered your question.

Comment: @Pipe2Path oh sorry so to the left of the answer you should see like a white check mark.  You can just click that to accept the answer.  I would recommend accepting answers in your other questions if they were helpful too.  Thanks

Comment: This is very nice, but apparently returning false from `beforeStop` raises an error at some point:
`TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'this.placeholder[0].parentNode.removeChild')`

Comment: @mccc can you give me the steps to reproduce the issue?

Comment: In the first fiddle you prepared, open the console and drag something in the second list.. As soon as the item gets back to its spot the error pops out.

Comment: Found the culprit: it should probably go in the `stop` callback - for good measure I changed the return to `$(this).sortable('cancel')`, but that throws the exception as well if used in `beforeStop`. Thanks!

Comment: @mccc Okay I'm glad you fixed it.  do you mind posting a link to a fiddle with your changes?  Thanks

Comment: I added the listB restriction [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PK3LE/8/); apparently, with current library versions, the only way to get the attributes of the source is to temporary tag the item on start: I don't like it, but seems to be the proper way.