# How to use jQuery UI component [drag and drop with sortable] without sorting?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to use drag and drop functionality between two  items. Some points as given below will give more understanding of problem.

**1.** There will be one static item list while loading page. (RIGHT-SIDE).(Available cities)
**2.** There will be one empty list (just box) while loading page. (LEFT-SIDE).
 (Selected cities)
**3.** Any items must not be sortable.
**4.** use this link for reference : `js-fiddle-link`

Comment: See if can give you a idea and serve as a template for your goal. http://jsfiddle.net/eddwinpaz/BXq5s/

Comment: Hi @eddwinpaz thanks, but this will not helpful for this scenario. :(

Comment: u want to be able to drag cities from right to left, but both the right and the left sides should not be sortable?

Comment: Yes, exactly @MandeepJain. I want only drag and drop functionality from one side to another.

Comment: Possible dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21143248/jquery-ui-draggable-and-droppable-but-not-sortable - In general, the solution would be to use the `.beforeStop()` event to prevent the sorting action.

Comment: Thanks guys for your great help, finally I did it. http://jsfiddle.net/vishalzanzrukia/8TCxY/57/ :) Thanks so much again